# How to extract a string like (010000 AAAAAAAA) from text

Tags: python, regex

I have an input file like this:

```
JTS
FF
010000 AAAAAAAA
text-text1.1
-text1.2-)

JTS
FF
020000 AAAAAAAA
text-text text
text-text2
-text2)
```

and using this code:

```
import re
input = open("input.txt", "r")

for line in input.read().split(")"):

 mySubString=line[line.find("JTS"):line.find("JTS")+3]
 mySubString2=line[line.find("FF"):line.find("FF")+2]

 print(mySubString,end=",")
 print(mySubString2,end=",")

result = re.findall(r'-\s*(.*?)(?=\s*-)', line)
 print(",".join(result)+"\n")
```

I'm getting this output:

```
JTS,FF,,text1.1,text1.2

JTS,FF,,text2
```

So my goal is to find a way to extract the string in the third line from every paragraph in order to print the output like this:

```
JTS,FF,010000 AAAAAAAA,text1.1,text1.2

JTS,FF,020000 AAAAAAAA,text2
```

Note that this string always comes at the 3rd line from every paragraph and its always consist of 15 character, and always start with a number and ends with with a letter.

Comment: If it always comes at the third line, why don't you just save that line?

Comment: I have tried doing that though the whole the paragraph is considered as one line, so i think my only way is with regex some how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the paragraph is represented as one line if because of the split.

I read the file and loop over it looking for the third line of each paragraph, and used the linebreak (\n) as a dilimiter between paragraphs, so everytime I find a linebreak I reset the index.

This way I manage to get the third line of each paragraph.

```
file = open("input.txt", "r")

third_lines = []
index = 0

for line in file:
    if index == 2:
        # rstrip() is to get rid of the linebreak
        third_lines.append(line.rstrip())
    index += 1
    if line == "\n":
        index = 0

print(third_lines)

# Output
# ['010000 AAAAAAAA', '020000 AAAAAAAA']
```

Answer (score 0):

If your final goal is to join the lines using commas until you encounter a closing bracket, then you don't need regular expressions at all. You can do it for example like that:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as input:
    result = ''
    for line in input.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 0:
            if not line.endswith(')'):
                result += '{}{}'.format(line, ',')
            else:
                result += line.rstrip(')')
                print(result)
        else:
            result = ''

# Output:
# JTS,FF,010000 AAAAAAAA,text-text1.1,-text1.2-
# JTS,FF,020000 AAAAAAAA,text-text text,text-text2,-text2
```

If you really feel like using regular expression for extracting text from the third line then following pattern should do: `r'^\d{6}\s\w{8}(?=\n)$'`. For example:

```
import re

third_lines = []
with open("input.txt", "r") as input:
    for line in input.readlines():
        match = re.match(r'^\d{6}\s\w{8}(?=\n)$', line)
        if match:
            third_lines.append(match.group())

print(third_lines)

# Output:
# ['010000 AAAAAAAA', '020000 AAAAAAAA']
```

---

Also note that opening the file as `input = open("input.txt", "r")` is [not a good practice](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Opening the file using `with` statement (e.g. `with open("input.txt", "r") as input`) ensures you that the file is properly closed once you finish processing it.